# Is uNhAddIns active enough?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm going to use [`uNhAddins`](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/) as my base structure for `NHibernate` session management. But I need to be sure that it is not an a stale project and is to be continued actively. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's a [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/unhaddins) where almost no thread goes unnoticed -> +1
- Quite a few people "use this" on [ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/8147) -> +1
- [Lots of committers and contributors](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/people/list) -> +1
- [Recent activity](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/updates/list) is a bit sparse but I wouldn't say dead

All in all, I think it's pretty safe to use.